# Applescript can't set name of file

Tags: applescript

So I'm trying to rename a file using Applescript. I searched it up and apparently the command is `set name of file theFile to theString`. I tried it and it didn't work. I got the error `-10006`, which (according to https://www.osstatus.com) is either `errAEWriteDenied`, `errOSACantAssign` or `telCAUnavail`, but I think it's probably the first one. Before you ask, I am the administrator of my machine and `path to desktop` links to the own Desktop to which I 100% have access. I don't know if that matters (it really shouldn't), but my Desktop is stored in my iCloud.

```
set thePath to the POSIX path of (path to desktop)
set theName to "hello world.txt"
set theFile to thePath & theName
set the name of file theFile to "hello.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the `Finder` or `System Events` is able to set the name. In Finder it’s pretty easy because the desktop of the current user is the root folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to "hello world.txt"
    set theName to "hello"
    set the name of file theFile to theName & ".txt"
end tell
```

By the way, the Finder doesn’t know about POSIX paths, it prefers HFS paths (colon separated)

Comment: In which environment do you run the code?

Comment: Script Editor on a MacBook Air 2019 with MacOS 11.4 Beta.

Comment: 11.4 or 12? Maybe there is a new setting to make in Monterey. Consider it’s a beta.

Comment: It's weird considering I tried running similar code for a person who had the same problem just days ago and it ran perfectly.

Comment: It’s supposed to run in Big Sur and lower. Do you have to grant Script Editor full disk access in Monterey?

Comment: I will see what I can do. Maybe the problem is on my side and it's just something really stupid I overlooked the entire time. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Turns out that I ran the code and it worked and then of course there was no file with the path I defined because it was renamed.